# socket recv on select()ed socket failing with etimedout

Tags: linux, sockets

I am writing a server-client program with following snippet of code to receive data.

```
    ret_l = select(readfds+1, &readfds, NULL,  NULL ,NULL);
    if(ret_l != -1)
    {
        if(FD_ISSET(myfd, &readfds))
        {
             ret_l = recv(myfd, buf, size_of_buf_array, 0);
             if(ret_l == -1)
                 return ;
         }
    }
```

As far I know, recv on select()ed file descriptor should receive data without fail. But recv in my code failing with error ETIMEDOUT. Somebody please tell me why is this happening. And also please tell me some workaround to receive data completely even after ETIMEDOUT.

Comment: What is the type of `readfds` in your code? From what I see in the docs, it should be a `fd_set`, a struct{int n,int[]} so that's nothing you can safely `+1` in the first parameter. Have you hacked the system and are using `int readfds` by chance?

Comment: There's no code here that inspects errno at the proper place.How and where do you decide that you get ETIMEDOUT ?

Comment: As I am using my companies framework, I removed some of my framework details and copied the code which is required to understand. And readfds is of type fd_set, first argument to select is max(fds returned by socket function)+1

Answer (score 7):

There are three possible reasons for seeing `ETIMEDOUT`:

1. The connection timed out inside `recv`, this is very unlikely to happen even once (but surely not several times).
2. You did not check success of `connect`, and the connection was never successfully established (maybe the firewall is dropping the connection attempts?). This is the likely reason.
3. Your sockets implementation is broken, this is very unlikely.

`select` does not generate `ETIMEDOUT`, only `connect` and  `recv` may. Although `select` can in rare cases report readiness when there is nothing to receive (older Linux kernels, this has presumably been fixed), the only thing that would happen in this case would be `recv` blocking.

`recv` may generate this error, but it's unlikely that a connection times out once it's established—if you don't pull the cable, or, as pointed out by nos, a NAT gateway could time out after some minutes of not doing anything. If a connection could be established, there is a route and someone is listening at the other end, so there is generally no *regular* reason for a timeout (of course it's possible, just not likely to happen all the time). This error *will* of course eventually happen if the connection really times out for some reason (regardless of blocking), but if anything it's a very exceptional condition, not a regular one.

`connect` failing is a condition that you may conceivably see due to many reasons (not reachable, firewall, server process not running, etc.) and it is something that will regularly happen, every time you try, for as long as the condition that causes it persists.

As to a workaround to receive data completely after `ETIMEDOUT`, there is none. `read` will give you what it has in its buffers (up to the maximum that you specify in the function call), or block, or fail. One of these three things, nothing else, ever.
Once it has failed, you already have everything that was available before the failure (there's nothing more to read on your end), and now the connection is gone, i.e. the socket is not usable any more.
The only thing you can do is create a new socket and establish a new connecton, and try again.

Comment: Note that connections timing out (i.e. you're sending data on an established connection, but no TCP response, normally ACKs, are received, TCP will time out the connection as retransmission timers expire) after the connection has been establised are quite common on e.g. long lived connections that carry little to no data for a while as NAT gateways and firewalls silently times out the connections.

Comment: Yes, a NAT gateway or stateful firewall timing out after, say 5 mins of doing nothing may be a valid reason, if you really don't send anything for that long. Though to me the question reads much more like the OP is sending something (presumably in a LAN, at least that's where I'd be testing when writing a server and a client) and just can't receive.

Answer (score 4):

Enabled TCP keepalive on socket causes ETIMEDOUT errno to be returned from **recv**().TCP keepalive is nice mechanism and you should definitely check it.

ETIMEDOUT can be returned by **send**() if the other end didn't acknowledge retransmitted data after some time. Check also TCP_USER_TIMEOUT socket option which can also cause ETIMEDOUT errno on socket.

You can check [this chapter](https://books.google.sk/books?id=ptSC4LpwGA0C&pg=PA200&lpg=PA200&dq=ETIMEDOUT%20socket%20write&source=bl&ots=Ks7FLogrNn&sig=4HyzsHGtRDmG_SLSjbal6OK-460&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZ7qDv_onQAhUGvhQKHf-8By8Q6AEIRDAG#v=onepage&q=ETIMEDOUT%20socket%20write&f=false) from famous book "Unix Network Programming".

Answer (score 1):

Er, shouldn't it be

```
select(myfd+1,&readfds,NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess. When a TCP connection is lost. `select` would return and set this fd to be readable. But `recv` will fail with error ETIMEDOUT.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is socket option `SO_RCVLOWAT`.

If value of it is greater than 1, then `select` of linux returns even there are only one byte available, and claims that the socket is readable.

When you call `recv` in this situation, it will block until timeout occurs (set by using SO_RCVTIMEO), because count of available bytes is smaller than the low water mark.

So, check if your code changes value of `SO_RCVLOWAT`. Default value is 1.

More information: [here](http://sock-raw.org/netsec/rcvlowat)

> The select(2) and poll(2) sys- tem calls currently do not respect the
>   SO_RCVLOWAT setting on Linux, and mark a socket  readable  when  even 
>   a single byte of data is available.  A subsequent read from the socket
>   will block until SO_RCVLOWAT bytes are available.

Comment: Why would you get ETIMEDOUT in such a case ?

Comment: It is quite clear that SO_RCVTIMEO is also changed. If it is not changed, then my answer does not solve the OP's problem.

Comment: Well, it's not clear at all that SO_RCVTIMEO is changed, errno should be EAGAIN in such a case. ETIMEDOUT could happen in other cases too.

Comment: @nos : Ok, sorry. You are right, recv does not ETIMEDOUT. I will fix my answer.